# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate side-by-side with Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS Ultimate 2013 from my Dreamspark for studens subscription. I would like to install VS Professional 2013 and use it sometime for some commercial stuff. I have MSDN subscription that I use in work. However when I installed VS Professional it appeared in Programs and Features list but I can only run VS Ulitmate.

Is there any way to run VS Professional?

Comment: No.  The Ultimate installer upgraded your existing Professional install to Ultimate.  I do *not* advice running that Professional uninstaller, that's liable to leave a mess.  Do note that your Dreamspark license is no longer valid after you leave school.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a specific version of visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783396/running-a-specific-version-of-visual-studio)