# Two parallel Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2013 Community and the installation of VS 2013 Ultimate replace the Community edition. How can I install the Ultimate edition without uninstall the Community edition?

Comment: Why do you want to keep two editions?

Comment: You cannot. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753311/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-side-by-side-with-professional

Comment: @Nimesh In our company we use the BYOD model, so we work with our Outlook and Visual Studio accounts. I want work on my personal projects with the Community edition.

Comment: You cannot, but I don't believe this would be in violation of any license requirements for Visual Studio, it may be more of a internal company violation. You should be able to legally work on both off-time projects an work projects with the same ultimate version of VS2013 as far as Microsoft goes. If your company doesn't like this, you're going to have to solve this in another way, like with virtual machines, two computers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio installations use a common base location and each addition you install on top of Professional/Community basically extends the Visual Studio installation to give an integrated environment.

It's how SQL Server Data Tools, BizTalk and other extensions are able to provide a stand-alone editor on a system that has no Visual Studio installation, but it also means that it will just "extend" your community edition.

Alternative options for you, if you want to work only with the license you have available for personal use are:

- Use [Windows' boot to VHD feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825691.aspx), allowing you to multi-boot into a Virtual machine, either for personal or work usage. This uses additional space, but also gives very good separation. If you're really good with `dism`, you may be able to create a base image for your personal and your work environment to save space.
- [Boot from a secondary harddrive using the windows Boot Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-multiple-operating-system-multiboot#1TC=windows-7).
- Use Hyper-V (or VMware or Virtual Box) on your Windows installation and create a virtual machine for either work or personal use of Visual Studio (or create two Virtual machines).
- [Create a Windows-to-go installation](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Putting-Windows-8-on-a-USB-Drive) on a USB drive and boot from that.
- Host one of your development environments in the cloud, use the [Visual Studio images on Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/08/azure-virtual-machine-images-for-visual-studio.aspx) for example.

Or use your work license for your personal use and try not to use the ultimate features ;). as far as licensing is concerned, you are licensed to use Visual Studio. As Lasse says, it loos like it may be a company policy issue instead of a Microsoft licensing issue. **Remark**: confirmation of that pending.